# Javascript jQuery click function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a very confusing problem.
I want to do some action within an HTML site, when a link is clicked.
I implemented the following code with a click event, which should handle this behaviour:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("Ready!");
  $( "a" ).click(function() {
    console.log("Alert!");
    alert("Test");
  });
});
```

I implmented it in the head and at the end of the body but nothing happens. I don't get the console.log or alert.
When I change the click to mouseover everything ist fine.
Do you have any suggestions?

Regards,
Jens

Comment: it should work until `a` is not added dynamically.

Comment: create a jsfiddle that shows your issue. which browser are you using?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bhaggbL9/ working...

Comment: I made a jsfiddle. I hope it will help you. Now while transforming my HTML to an example for jsfiddle I recognized somethin strange. I use JQuery 1.11.1 und JQuery UI 1.11. When the two js scripts are included everything is fine. When the css of JQuery UI comes along, the click doesn't work ... I'm a little bit confused - http://jsfiddle.net/niffchen/udL56ww6/1/

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("Ready!");
  $( "a" ).on("click",function() {
    console.log("Alert!");
    alert("Test");
  });
});
```

because some versions of Jquery don't support the click function alone

Comment: Really? `.click` was added in V1.0. `.click` is shorthand for `.on("click")`

Comment: `.click`  is older than `.on` . `.click` was added in V1.0. and `.on` was added in  V1.7 => please see : `.click` = http://api.jquery.com/click/  and `.on` = http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

Is the `a` present when the page is loaded? If not, you need to modify your event binding a little.
Also, you can try to prevent the default behavior.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("Ready!");
  $(document).click("a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Alert!");
    alert("Test");
  });
});
```

Comment: I made a jsfiddle. I hope it will help you. Now while transforming my HTML to an example for jsfiddle I recognized somethin strange. I use JQuery 1.11.1 und JQuery UI 1.11. When the two js scripts are included everything is fine. When the css of JQuery UI comes along, the click doesn't work ... I'm a little bit confused - http://jsfiddle.net/niffchen/udL56ww6/1/

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that you need to do is check you jquery library to make sure that you have included it or not?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

If it still doesn't work you should check your anchor attribute and change it like bellow

```
<a href="#">alert</a> or <a>alert</a>
```

So this code will work

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("Ready!");
  $( "a" ).click(function() {
    console.log("Alert!");
    alert("Test");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include Jquery in your head:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("Ready!");
  $('a[href$="google"]').on("click",function() {
    console.log("Alert!");
    alert("Test");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="google">google</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Otherwise you can get DOM elements by using: getElementsById and add id in your link

Comment: made a jsfiddle. I hope it will help you. Now while transforming my HTML to an example for jsfiddle I recognized somethin strange. I use JQuery 1.11.1 und JQuery UI 1.11. When the two js scripts are included everything is fine. When the css of JQuery UI comes along, the click doesn't work ... I'm a little bit confused - jsfiddle.net/niffchen/udL56ww6/1

Answer (score 0):

please see this :  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/udL56ww6/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        console.log("Bereit!");
        $( "a" ).click(function() {
            console.log("Alert!");
            alert("BBB wurden mit dem CCC synchronisiert");
        });
    });
```

its works.

Are you sure you've added the correct version jQuery?

Comment: Yes i do. But I recognized, that if I implement the CSS of JQURY UI, that this problem appears. If I delete it, then it works as aspected ... consufing. You can see the jsfiddle above!

Comment: see : <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js". this is wrong in "jsfiddle.net". please upload jquery-1.11.1.min.js on "jsfiddle.net". like :     <script type="text/javascript" src="www.jquery.com/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: Hello. Sorry, I forgot to post the new update link. This is my first time with jsfiddle ... http://jsfiddle.net/niffchen/udL56ww6/27/. If you change the URls for the css files into nirvana than everything ist fine. If one of this css files is working you don't get alert box.